# how to change char arry from string to integer (encoding problem)

Tags: arrays, c, qt, char

Hello everyone I am new to C and learning new stuff daily. I am working on a project which involves qt creator and controller. so basically I am getting pin(password) from qt application and sending it over UDP to my controller and there I am checking whether the pin matches with pin stored in controller.

I will share my procedure also.

when key 1 is pressed, inside on_pressbutton() I get first value

```
 pass[0] = 1;
```

when key 2 is pressed, inside on_pressbutton() I get second value

```
 pass[1] = 2;
```

when key 3 is pressed, inside on_pressbutton() I get third value

`pass[2] = 3`;

when key 4 is pressed, inside on_pressbutton() I get fourth value

```
 pass[3] = 4;
```

I store the pin in my unsigned char pass array as the above following and send it to controller over UDP

In controller I have other unsigned char array where I have hard coded the correct password for checking

```
unsigned char correctPassword [4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

In this way the password/pin matches but when I initialize  it as this

```
unsigned char correctPassword [4] = "1234";
```

the password doest match when I do memcmp. Now how do I change the second initialization to get it matched.
Because in actual project the correctPassword will be taken from text file .
Please suggest how do i proceed .

Comment: Note that `{1,2,3,4}` is not the same as the single integer `1234`. Which is what you seem to be thinking.

Comment: The easiest thing to do may be to iterate over the arrays and compare each digit/character with: `pass[i] == correctPassword[i] - '0';`. That is, convert each ascii digit to a decimal int for the comparison.

Comment: also note that `unsigned char correctPassword [4] = "1234";` is a string, with a 5th byte NUL terminator, that you haven't allocated enough space for. That should be `unsigned char correctPassword [5] = "1234";` at least.

Comment: What is the actual problem that the `"1234"` initialization is supposed to solve?